# Remember path used in intents to override onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onbackpressed

I am dealing with a certain problem in android and I struggle to find a viable solution.

The situation is as follows:-

I have 4 activities `A`,`B`,`C` and `D` and two possible paths :

Path 1 : `A,B,C,D`

Path 2 : `A,B',D`

B and B' refer to the same activity but with different views ( a recyclerview is used in here ) depending on the activity I am initially ie B or A.

What I want to do is basically follow the paths like that : `A,B,C,D` ( direct ) and `D,C,B,A` ( when back is constantly pressed ). The same with the second one : `A, B', D` ( direct ) and `D,B',A` ( when back is constantly pressed ).

I have a lot of problems when back is pressed so I know that I have to override `onBackPressed`. But how exactly can I figure out in which case I am ( path 1 or path 2 )?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: see my answer hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: Hi, please check my comments. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Why do you need to override `onBackPressed()` at all? Standard Android behaviour will just take you back to the previous `Activity`. That sounds exactly like what you want.

Comment: Hi David Wasser, the exact situation is actually as follows : Path1 is with 4 activities A,B,C,D and a final fragment called E where I display things according to what is chosen in the list view in C. D is the basis of the fragment E. The problem I was facing was that when back pressing in E my app crashed. So I overrided onResume() to come back to activity C. But then I had the problems mentionned above... Still, I struggle a lot with Andy's proposition. I manage to deal with a lot of paths but when I am in E, I can't manage to know in which path I am : 1 or 2.

Comment: What usually happens whitout overriding onBackPressed() is that I do C --> E and back pressing leads me to C and then backpressing leads me to E and so on as if there was a cycle !

Comment: Please do NOT use the suggestion from Andy. This will cost you a lot of effort and unnecessarily complicate your code. None of this is necessary. Go back to using standard Android behaviour and lets try to solve your original problem

Comment: Thanks for your advice David, but how can I manage to do it taking into account what I said previously ? Is the situation clear enough ?

Comment: Any help guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in one.

```
// Add activity
public static void addActivities(String actName, Activity _activity) {
    if (Config.screenStack == null)
        Config.screenStack = new HashMap<String, Activity>();
    if (_activity != null)
        Config.screenStack.put(actName, _activity);
}

// Remove Activity
public static void removeActivity(String key) {
    if (Config.screenStack != null && Config.screenStack.size() > 0) {
        Activity _activity = Config.screenStack.get(key);
        if (_activity != null) {
            Config.screenStack.remove(key);
            _activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

User add activities before setContentView to add into the stack.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addActivities("DemoActivity", DemoActivity.this)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_feed_post);
}
```

If you want to finish all activity when you exist from app you can [**see this code.**](http://developerandroidguide.blogspot.in/2017/04/how-to-remove-particular-activity-from.html)

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer. 

What I did is I created a class called StackHandler and whenever I want to add an activity I call StackHandler.addActivities(...)  and when I want to remove one  I call StackHandler.removeActivities(...).
But I don't exactly know where to put them. What I did is I put on each onCreate of the activities A,B,C,D  StackHandler.addActivities( "name of the activity I am in " ) and I override everytime onBackPressed() to remove the activity I am in. But this doesn't work for me !

Comment: What happens is that ( after doing A-B-C-D ) when I press back on D, I go back to C but when I press back in C it leads me to D. That's the problem I am facing right now

Comment: Now, what I do is, say I am in activity D, I want to go back to C after pressing back button, I override then onBackPressed() as follows : Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext(), C.class); StackHandler.removeActivity("D"); startActivity(intent);

I use the same logic for the rest of the activities. It works fine for Path1 but there are problems when I am in B' because it leads me to B ...

Comment: @MastafaF For E.g. When you Go from A-B-C-D now when you BackPress you just remove that Particular activity like removeActivity("Activity Name D") do not set super.onBackpress().

Comment: If you are in B then it is also very simple Just call the removeActivity("Activity B") before the startActivity so in this situation you don't have the 2 stack for activity B.